# How to represent dbus type b(oss) in python?

Tags: python, dbus

I'm working on a Mpris V2.1 interface with python.

The interfaces are described in the document: 
[http://www.mpris.org/2.1/spec/Playlists.html#Property:ActivePlaylist](http://www.mpris.org/2.1/spec/Playlists.html#Property%3aActivePlaylist)

The signature shows it's complex type contains boolean, object and strings. I just wonder how to represent the type in python. Do I have a provider a list or tuple contains each element ? I've tested it but seems not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to D-Bus specification, `(b(oss))` is a struct of two elements, first  is a boolean, second is a struct of three elements: an object path and two strings. In python this maps to something like:

```
dbus.Struct((dbus.Boolean(a_boolean),
             dbus.Struct((dbus.ObjectPath(s1),
                          dbus.String(s2),
                          dbus.String(s3)))),
            signature="(b(oss))")
```

but it can be used as if it was simply a python tuple like:

```
( a_boolean, (s1, s2, s3) )
```

Are you writing a client or a server? In the latter case you should also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740903/python-dbus-how-to-export-interface-property) which provides details on exporting properties using python dbus module.